# How to control each image from an array of CSS `url()` values?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to control each image I have in my `const imgURLArray`, if possible via `class` or `id`.
If this is only possible via JS, could someone help me or teach me how to do it?

I have created a [CodePen](//codepen.io/cat999/pen/rNvdrNb) to see the infinite gallery in action.

```js
const imgURLArray = [
    "url(img1)",
    "url(img2)",
    "url(img3)",
    "url(img4)",
  ];
```

Comment: Please try to further clarify where and what are you trying to achieve. Currently it's very unclear.

Comment: @MalwareMoon i would like for example on mouse hover on each image show something like info text photography

Comment: To get hold of element by #id. Vanilla javascript uses document.getElementById("whatever your id is"). To do the same via class you can use document.getElementsByClassName("whatever your class name is"). Documentation for those: by (id)[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp], (class)[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp],(name)[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp],(tag name)[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp]

Comment: @MalwareMoon is exactly this the issue i need to add Id which i don't have right now...have a look https://codepen.io/cat999/pen/rNvdrNb

Comment: Looking at your code, each image does have a .sliderImage class you could use. I don't see any other more specific value you can grab. This means that you would have to add something like an id if you needed a specific image, or orient yourself via it's background-image. Do you need this specificity or is this enough?

Comment: Exactly, I don't know how to specify more there, at the moment I cannot control each image..   only via .sliderImage class, but the issue there is that I control all of those in group and not singular : /

Comment: You can control each image if you get it by class by document.getElementsByClassName("class")[collectionIndex].doSomething() but I doubt that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing your createImageGrid function to this:

```js
function createImageGrid() {
  for(let y = 0; y < rowNum; y++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = rowClass;
      for(let x = 0; x < imgNum; x++) {
        let image = document.createElement("div");
        image.className = imageClass;
        // This gives it id
        image.id = `image${y}-${x}`
        row.appendChild(image);
      }
    document.querySelector(containerSelector).appendChild(row);
    
    // Add the images to our representation
    imgRep.push(gsap.utils.toArray(row.querySelectorAll(imageSelector)));
  }
  
  rows = document.querySelectorAll(rowSelector),
  imgMidIndex = Math.floor(imgNum / 2),
  rowMidIndex = Math.floor(rowNum / 2);
}
```

With that your images will have id of image${ITS_ROW}-${ITS_COLUMN} and you will be able to pinpoint the exact image this way.

**Edit**
(Based on comment.)

Just replace your function createImageGrid() {} with this one and it will give your images property id that is = `image${y}-${x}`.

Output shown here:
[image: Image id's]

Comment: Many thanks, malware moon could you show me this in action in my code pen? it
would definitely clarify everything and I would very much appreciated!

Comment: Edited my answer. I sadly do not have code pen account, to send you done code. But you can do it. It's only CTRL+C CTRL+V :)

Comment: when add your code is all black malware have a look

https://cdpn.io/pen/debug/rNvdrNb?authentication_hash=PNrvYyRzEvVM

Comment: it works sorry!

Comment: It did not work when you posted it, it does now so probably some processing time. I changed nothing that even could break the code.

Comment: In that case if, this is desired outcome, please close the question by selecting the correct answer.